# App engine flexible - auto scaling properly

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

My problem: My application cannot handle multiple (order of 100s) requests.

How can I set up a cost effective auto scaling environment?

I've read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml) but it is not clear to me how can I set up the proper environment to handle my situation.

Can I estimate the number of instances, cpu_utilization, among other parameters, accordingly to my expected requests?

My current yaml (default) is:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 0.5
  memory_gb: 2.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can estimate the resources either empirically, or you can refer to existing benchmarks, but the CPU load for example depends a lot of the processing that you are performing for each request that you receive.

This is an example that you can start building from.
You may start with smaller number of `max_num_instances` and fine tune the values as you go:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 15
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
  target_concurrent_requests: 100
```

- At any moment, at least one instance will be up and running for your app.
- No matter how much the load will grow, there will be no more than 15 instances of the app.
- The `cool_down_period_sec` will not allow two subsequent scaling operations to be performed within less that 180 seconds.
- The `target_utilization` and `target_concurrent_requests` represent thresholds that can trigger a scaling operation.